# Creating a order from the backend, adding quantity calculates a incorrect price

Tags: orders, products, sales, quantity, price

Somehow Magento calculates an incorrect price when adding an order from the backend.

This problem only occurs on products with a custom option field and when the locale is set to a land that uses commas in prices, instead of dots.

In my case, that is Dutch.

To demonstrate the steps I take:

1. Adding a product, goto:

   Sales -> Orders -> Create new order
2. Click 'add product'

   Select a product with a custom option, so a popup appears. 
   *Remember to set the locale first to another one (for instance: Netherlands) before you add the custom option product, else the miscalculation won't happen.*

   [image: Adding product Magento]
3. When you click '**ok**' you will see that the quantity is multiplied by 100.

   [image: Product is multiplied]

This a something strange, on a fresh installation of Magento it also occurs.

My best bet would be there is a problem with the javascript parsing the prices incorrectly, because of the format used (`.` instead of `,`) .

I know that I can go a step further in the 'adding product' process, where you can edit the quantity. But, I still want to get this working normal for clients.

Can someone suggest the proper solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey, could u tell me the Magento version u r using? Thanks :) Nice find, btw :D

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a problem for all Magento installations. I'm using Magento 1.8 but i also tested it out on the latest version 1.9.0.1. Could you take a look at it? Hope you make some fix for this :).

Comment: @simonthesorcerer Did you maybe found some info/fix on this one? Would certainly hope so :)

Comment: My best bet would be that you had some weird browser caching problem with some of the javascript parsing the prices incorrectly. Have you tried to clear the browser cache after switching the language? What browser have you tried?I've tested this on a vanilla clean install of Magento v1.9.0.1 with sample data and it does not happen.

Comment: Did you tried to set the language of Magento to the Netherlands? Or a country that uses comma's instead of dots for the decimals? Because i did a clean install with different versions. And all installs had the same problem. I usually disable all Magento cachings for development. Also browser cache. So that is not the problem. Besides that, more dutch developers confirmed the problem. The problem is most likely something to do with the javascript in that section.

Comment: so the issues occurs when you use a , instead of a . in the backend? or it occurs even when not using a decimal?

Comment: Can you try same thing with the default currency using fresh Magento installation? So we can debug problem in detail.

Comment: @SanderMangel it only occurs when you use a , in the backend.

Comment: @MageComp it was also tested on a fresh install. It only occurs when u are using euro.

Comment: @AmitBera, I'm voting to leave open as the OP is still actively responding to questions and suggestions (22 hours ago).

Comment: ok. yes.you can do..

Comment: from where you have changed (, instead of .) ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have got the setup wrong on your locale. Either in one of your translate.csv files or the backend administraction itself. You are correct in thinking the issue is around the , against the . Just ensure this is correctly classified in the backend and the issue should be resolved